# Intentar hacer lo mismo en json de estos códigos en XML

Tags: c#, json

Antes usaba muchos el XML para guardar y leer datos que tenía en el formulario. Por ejemplo en este caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
```

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Guardar_y_cargar_datos_en_archivo_xml
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    // Guarda los datos introducidos a parte de crear el archivo "miXML.xml".
    private void button_Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("miXML.xml");
        w.WriteStartElement("MiInfo");
        w.WriteElementString("TextBox", textBox1.Text);
        w.WriteElementString("CheckBox", checkBox1.Checked.ToString());
        w.WriteElementString("radioButton1", radioButton1.Checked.ToString());
        w.WriteElementString("radioButton2", radioButton2.Checked.ToString());
        w.WriteEndElement();
        w.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create("miXML.xml");
            r.ReadStartElement("MiInfo");
            textBox1.Text = r.ReadElementContentAsString();
            checkBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(r.ReadElementContentAsString());
            radioButton1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(r.ReadElementContentAsString());
            radioButton2.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(r.ReadElementContentAsString());
            r.ReadEndElement();
            r.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            //
        }

    }
}
```

}

El archivo se genera en el disco duro o SSD hoy en día y pone esto.

```
<MiInfo>
<TextBox>Texto y textos</TextBox>
<CheckBox>True</CheckBox>
<radioButton1>False</radioButton1>
<radioButton2>True</radioButton2>
</MiInfo>
```

Me funciona de maravilla para lo que es el XML y me lo recomendaron en este foro hace años, desde el 2.008.

Ahora, veo mucho con el santo JSON.

Quiero hacer el mismo ejemplo de recuperar y guardar datos como se hizo el XML.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

*Aviso: Daré un rodeo enorme para responder lo mejor que pueda tu pregunta, mil disculpas si me he desviado del tema en concreto*

Tanto el XML y el JSON permiten guardar datos, pero sobre todo permiten guardar OBJETOS, y como C# es un lenguaje orientado a objetos ambos funcionan muy bien.

El uso común es para intercambiar objetos entre distintos sistemas (webservices y APIs), pero también se usan como archivos de configuración y pequeñas bases de datos (entre otros usos), aunque yo prefiero usar una base de datos SQLite para guardar datos de forma local.

Yo leí y comenté tu [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582677/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-mejor-formato-para-guardar-y-recuperar-archivos-para-c) anterior, y ahora que veo tu código me queda claro el porqué de tus dudas (por eso es bueno poner código en las preguntas)

Es difícil competir con la simpleza de tu código, pero es que el ejemplo es muy ad-hoc, si tú tienes un formulario de 30 campos o más, tienes que hacer 30 veces algo como esto para guardar:

```
w.WriteElementString("TextBox", textBox1.Text);
```

Y otras 30 algo como esto para leer:

```
textBox1.Text = r.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

Ahora imagina que UNO de esos 30 campos es una lista, o son los datos de una tabla ¿Ya no es tan simple verdad?

Y tú problema principal con ese código de ejemplo, es que lo has programado como se hacía en VB6, una forma de programación antigua. Así que lo primero es cambiar el asunto a una forma más moderna usando Clases y Binding.

Yo crearé este ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- textbox1: Es un campo de texto libre
- textbox2: Muestra el largo de textbox1
- checkbo1: Un checkbox

Luego creó un Clase que representa el modelo del formulario:

```
public class UnaClase
{
    public string Texto { get; set; } = "hola";
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get { return Texto.Length; } }
}
```

Si te fijas la propiedad `Cantidad` solo tiene `Get`, porque lo que yo quiero es mostrar la cantidad letras que tiene `Texto`, es decir es dependiente de él

El form queda:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private UnaClase datos { get; set; } = new UnaClase();
    private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    public Form1(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bindingSource.DataSource = datos;
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Texto", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "Cantidad", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingSource, "isChecked", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

En el constructor configuramos los binding, enlazando cada componente con una propiedad del Objeto `datos`. De esta manera, en un formulario de 30 campos ya no son 60 veces que guardo y recupero, son solo 30 pero solo UNA vez al principio, Y si te fijas ni siquiera me preocupo por los "tipos" de datos, si es bool, si es string o int pasa a ser irrelevante. Pero es que estamos con WindowsForms, en tecnologías más modernas esto no se realiza, basta configurar la vista correctamente, es decir de 30 pasa a 0. Aunque también existen otras técnicas para automatizar esto, pero es harina de otro costal

Ejecuto el programa y en texbox1 escribo "hola mucho gusto"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pone en "Largo Texto" = 16, automáticamente!!! sin más código

**Ya hombre, pero ¿cómo rayos guardo el JSON!!?**

Creamos un botón guardar con su respectivo evento "button1_Click", además yo usaré la librería `Newtonsoft`, porque por la imagen que publicaste veo que usas .net 4.x, con .net más modernos no es necesario porque ya trae un conversor superior.

El evento queda:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
    File.WriteAllText("miarchivo.json", json);
}
```

Y el archivo `miarchivo.json` se ve de esta manera:

```
{"Texto":"hola","isChecked":false,"Cantidad":4}
```

**¿Y para leerlo?**

Creamos otro button2 con su respectivo evento

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UnaClase>(File.OpenText("miarchivo.json").ReadToEnd());
    bindingSource.DataSource = datos;
}
```

*Nota: Existen otras maneras para hacer binding*

---

Con todo esto, te queda un código limpio, fácil de mantener y mejorar.

**¿Podrías haber hecho lo mismo con XML?**

**Bueno, si! :P**

Al cambiar la lógica de tu código por Clases y Binding, es posible hacer algo parecido en XML, porque tu código no tiene problemas con el formato en que guardas, tiene problemas de "una forma de programación" que es cansina y que a la larga termina siendo más compleja.

Es que ambos sirven para guardar objetos y ese es el punto importante. Pero XML va en caída libre, porque es un formato cuya especificación es compleja y genera mucho texto (namespaces, tag de inicio y de término). En cambio el JSON es un formato simple, son pocas las reglas que existen para formarlo, pesa menos y es transversal a los lenguajes más usados. Eso ha hecho que las herramientas y librería para serializar y deseariazar solo mejoren con el JSON, pero con el XML estas herramientas caen al olvido, y nadie de/serializa a mano, todos ocupamos estas herramientas

Comment: Muy buena información, muy valiosa para mi que hasta hice una copia y la guardé en Word para siempre.

Hice lo mismo antes de saber que me han respondido aquí la versión .NET 7.0 con el XML y funciona igual. Intenté hacerlo con WPF también con .NET 7.0 y no funciona, no se escribe igual, me da errores. Haré ejemplos que has puesto con JSON haber si me sale, también la forma que dices actual en XML. A mi me enseñaron hacerlo tedioso precisamente el que viene de VB6, y así me ha funcionado hasta ahora, como dices, es cierto, muy tedioso a la larga. Voy a codear y les comento, con .NET 7.0.

Comment: Hola de nuevo:
Hice tu código con .NET 7 y me da error que muestro en esta captura.
Ver captura.
https://i.postimg.cc/SKRzXPFD/Captura2.jpg
Gracias.

Comment: @Meta Cada tecnología de .net (winform, WPF, UWP, MAUI, Blazor, etc) Estado se hace de manera similar pero no exactamente igual. Este error que me muestras es en WPF?

Comment: Trabajo con el Windows Form .NET 7.0.

Comment: @Meta Lo probé en WinForm 7.0 y funciona, puedes pegarme unas fotos con el código completo?

Comment: Hola @Yuseef Aquí la captura completa.
https://i.postimg.cc/jt4cL9xt/Captura3.jpg

Y del fallo.
https://i.postimg.cc/SKkqsvLZ/Captura3.jpg

Gracias.